# HTTPD Restrict Acces to File via Web App

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I would like to restrict access to a file until the user has paid for it.  This is easy enough if I served the file via a web app, but it seems more efficient to have httpd serve the file.  Is there a way to get apache to ask a web app if it can serve a file before serving it?  As I'm typing this it seems like it should be trivial but I'm not coming up with a good answer via google.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends a bit on your setup.
If you are generating the links to the protected file in your application and you are fine that the link is different for each user, then [mod-auth-token](http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-token/) could work for you.
The link will also expire after a configurable amount of time, this prevents that users share the link.